# jQuery validate not preventing submit in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use the jQuery validation plugin to add client side validation. In Firefox and Chrome this works fine.

In IE, the validation is showing up as in error, but the form submit is not stopped. Why might this be happening?

Example code:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
<fieldset>
    <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="cname">Name</label>
        <em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
        <em>*</em><input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="curl">URL</label>
        <em>  </em>
        <input id="curl" name="url" size="25"  class="url" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="ccomment">Your comment</label>
        <em>*</em>
        <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"  class="required"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And the JS

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
```

This is the example taken straight from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation, which I'm assuming should work, but doesn't seem to for IE (I'm testing with IE 8 on XP)

Comment: Sorry, I left my psychic pants at home. Could you please post the code which is causing the issue.

Comment: make sure you return false on validation

Comment: @Tigra If the jquery validation plugin has been configured correctly, that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using jQuery version 1.7, which is not supported by version 1.9 of the validation plugin, dropping back to version 1.6.1 fixed the problem.